# Search for any matching keyword

Tags: search

I'm writing search functionality in root magento file.

```
<?php
 require_once('app/Mage.php');
 umask(0);
 Mage::app('default');
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();  
 $searchKeyword = 'kalmari123 abc'
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array('attribute'=>'sku','like'=>"%$searchKeyword%"),
    array('attribute'=>'name','like'=>"%$searchKeyword%")
));
foreach ($collection as $_product)
  {
    echo $_product->getSku();
  }
```

kalmari123 is the sku for product.
It's giving correct result if `$searchKeyword = 'kalmari123';` but it shows nothing if I'm using `$searchKeyword = 'kalmari123 abc'`. How can I make it work? I want to search if any of the given keyword is matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **REGEXP**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$searchKeyword = 'kalmari123 abc';

$searchKeyword = explode(' ', $searchKeyword);
$searchKeyword = implode('|', $searchKeyword);

$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'sku','regexp'=>"$searchKeyword"),
        array('attribute'=>'name','regexp'=>"$searchKeyword")
    ));

foreach ($collection as $_product) {
    echo $_product->getSku();
}
```